# Whats wrong with this script? - python, gmail, smtp_ssl

Tags: python, ssl, smtp, gmail

Haven't used python in some time, but need a script to email myself alerts etc.

Why wont this work? I switched to using ssl after gmail told me an insecure app tried to access.

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEText("TEST FILE")

me = 'me@gmail.com'
you = me

msg['Subject'] = 'This is a test' 
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

#username and password here
username = 'username'
password = 'password'


# Send the message via gmail with ssl
s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com:465')
s.login(username,password)
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

The error I get when I attempt to run it is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Desktop\emailTest.py", line 24, in <module>
    s.login(username,password)
  File "F:\Python34\lib\smtplib.py", line 652, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsJy\n5.7.14 DZytmH_1-mwcm6vOSQ8erg0EXRR-OzQ6-shmU4noqJdeRPdzO62-ZIC2GPMtLNj3u5-qxJ\n5.7.14 ZT3QrgTcO7d5zpJ8UtO2vvTFU1G2rmMWfBwpvavpD8__GaVCWHWszps1GzZqxnxJbqD1DA\n5.7.14 EX-9IS6nxe9-giAhaFj5FryML1r0Qr1wcUH9tEmRdjX4KlO1xX4BhPBMJ5GJ7imrzrLZUv\n5.7.14 NgG0BaLrwWzUK1SSd_bqptGe15rg> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 uo9sm14972088wjc.49 - gsmtp')
```

Comment: "Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again" ... it is in the message

Comment: I am logged in with my browser

Comment: This script works for me. Maby you have double step authentication turned on?

Comment: I should mention I have dots in the email address, which I recently learned are ignored? Could this be the issue? The username is just the address excluding @gmail* right?

Comment: Or the "app" password is needed rather than the username "password". "app" passwords are generated for such purposes.

Comment: Login is address w/o "@gmail.com". Dots do not matter. Have you read this: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 ?

Comment: I have read the cited support guide, and followed the instructions to no avail. I do not have 2 step authentication enabled.

Comment: Still cant get it working.

Comment: Got it working by temporarily turning off strict permissions.

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

But I would like to find out how to give my script app permissions.